# how to import csv / generate user table at supabase

Tags: csv, authentication, import, supabase

Good day everyone, Can someone help me with generating supabase user and password
what I want to achieve is to able import user csv to supabase auth.
for now Im able to generate user and password with navicat data generation but I cannot use that password because it's encrypted. does someone have a workaround for this

[Generate user from navicat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qLw1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Much better to write a custom application and create all users and disable email confirmation on the Supabase page.

I use Dart and Flutter, but you can do it on other languages as well:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'your_supabase_url',
    anonKey:
        'your_anon_key',
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> _createUsers() async {
    final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      final response =
          await supabase.auth.signUp('test_$i@test.com', 'your_password');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'New app',
            ),
            IconButton(onPressed: _createUsers, icon: const Icon(Icons.start)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a software like dbeaver to connect to supabase and to import your csv file from you local drive. Very easy.
You'll find your supabase database settings in the project settings menu.